# Configure CkEditor toolbar in Angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a directive for CkEditor. I need to configure ckeditor toolbar in the directive only, needs help... here is my directive

```
.directive('fosCkEditor', ['$compile',
function($compile) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {

            var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]);

            ck.on('pasteState', function () {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
                });
            });

            ngModel.$render = function (value) {
                ck.setData(ngModel.$modelValue);
            };
        }
    };

}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use **ng-ckeditor** ?:

https://github.com/esvit/ng-ckeditor

From ng-ckeditor docs:

```
<textarea ckeditor="editorOptions" ng-model="modelName"></textarea>
// add dependency
angular.module('app', ['ngCkeditor'])

// setup editor options
$scope.editorOptions = {
    language: 'ru',
    uiColor: '#000000'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one:

https://github.com/lemonde/angular-ckeditor

```
 // Editor options.
 $scope.options = {
   language: 'en',
   allowedContent: true,
   entities: false
 };
```